# Custom Control Load Issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

We have a custom control named HostStatusControl. When we are placing the control to a form, we are getting the following error message. `ICEIOBridge` is one of the CLI libraries referred by the control. If we remove ICEIOBridge, the error message will be shown with another CLI library referred by the control

What could be the reason for the issue?

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Failed to create component 'HostStatusControl'.  The error message follows:

'System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'ICEIOBridge, Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

File name: 'ICEIOBridge, Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

   at NeST.ICE.UI.TitlePanel.HostStatusControl..ctor()



WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.

To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.

Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.

To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

'
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

---

We tried with the Fusion Log viewer and the log content is given below.

Information from VS Error Message

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Failed to create component 'HostStatusControl'.  The error message follows:

'System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'TestCLI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3045f9e53eded2d0' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

File name: 'TestCLI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3045f9e53eded2d0'

   at NeST.ICE.UI.TitlePanel.HostStatusControl..ctor()



Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll

Running under executable  D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe

--- A detailed error log follows. 


=== Pre-bind state information ===

LOG: User = TVM\monisha.mj

LOG: DisplayName = TestCLI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3045f9e53eded2d0
(Fully-specified)

LOG: Appbase = file:///D:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/

LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL

Calling assembly : (Unknown).

===

LOG: This bind starts in default load context.

LOG: Using application configur...'
---------------------------
OK
```

**Fusion Log1 (Devenv)**

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (12/5/2012 @ 1:29:11 PM) ***

The operation was successful.
Bind result: hr = 0x0. The operation completed successfully.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = TVM\monisha.mj
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.AppDomainManager, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
(Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///D:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = devenv.exe
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Download of application configuration file was attempted from file:///D:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/devenv.exe.Config.
LOG: Found application configuration file (D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.Config).
LOG: Private path hint found in configuration file: PublicAssemblies;PrivateAssemblies;CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TemplateProviders;PrivateAssemblies\DataCollectors;PrivateAssemblies\DataCollectors\x86;CommonExtensions\Microsoft\Editor;CommonExtensions\Platform\Debugger.
LOG: Using application configuration file: D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.AppDomainManager, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
LOG: Reusing an assembly instance that was previously loaded (C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.AppDomainManager\v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.AppDomainManager.dll).
```

**Fusion Log2(Windows Forms Application1.vshost.exe)**

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (12/5/2012 @ 1:29:33 PM) ***

The operation was successful.
Bind result: hr = 0x0. The operation completed successfully.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  D:\TestApplication\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Release\WindowsFormsApplication1.vshost.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = TVM\monisha.mj
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///D:/TestApplication/WindowsFormsApplication1/WindowsFormsApplication1/bin/Release/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = WindowsFormsApplication1.vshost.exe
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Download of application configuration file was attempted from file:///D:/TestApplication/WindowsFormsApplication1/WindowsFormsApplication1/bin/Release/WindowsFormsApplication1.vshost.exe.config.
LOG: Configuration file D:\TestApplication\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Release\WindowsFormsApplication1.vshost.exe.config does not exist.
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL
LOG: Found assembly by looking in the GAC.
LOG: Binding succeeds. Returns assembly from C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll.
LOG: Assembly is loaded in default load context.
```

Comment: Use Fuslogvw.exe to diagnose assembly resolution problems.  Some odds this assembly needs to go in the GAC so it can still be found at design time.  You'll have to give it a strong name.

Comment: Hans: The detailed error log from Fusion Log viewer is added to the post. Can you help us identify the issue

Comment: Sigh.  You posted the wrong one.  Post the first failure.

Comment: Hans: I have added the fresh log. Can you check?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like DLL hell, try removing all references, perform a clean on the build and reference everything back again.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, it can be because of two things:

1. If FileNotFoundException has been occured on an existing file, i.e. you are sure that the file exists (in file-system or GAC), it may its because of it's version. I mean when you have a dll named A which references B, and B itself references C, then when C changes it's version, then you should re-build B against the new dll C, and then rebuild A. In result, I think re-building the user control (and all underlying dependant your own dlls) with VS2010 may help.
2. Another possibility is that you're trying to run a dll on a 64bit OS but one (or more) of it's underlying dependant dlls is compiled only for 32bit OS. In result, I think re-building the user control with "**x86**" option instead of "**any cpu**" may help.

Comment: Yasser: Can you check my post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761539/cli-build-for-x86-platform-shows-that-it-is-build-for-any-cpu

Comment: @Maanu, SO says it has been removed!